# Asp.net mvc custom validation of list items in complex class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm displaying records with details in a view (using asp.net mvc). User has to enter serial numbers and post back the view. I would like to check if user has not made a mistake and all the serial numbers are unique in the detail list. If the serial number is accidentally inserted twice I would like to indicate the user the exact fields that contains those duplicate serial numbers.

I have these classes (they are more complex):

```
public class Record 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
}
```

I tried using custom validation attribute but there is no way I can access the whole list from inside the detail view to check if this is an unique serial number.
If I use validation attribute on Details inside Record class,

```
[SerialNoShouldBeUnique]
public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
```

I can check the fact and indicate user that there are duplicates, but I can't mark exactly those details erroneous.

I found somewhere to validate whole detail list and iterate through elements and add validation errors using Detail[i] indexes but I'm displaying details in the view using [this type of item indexing](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) so I can't easily access those indexes.
I could check those serial numbers in controller action. If I find duplicates, traverse through ModelState, find those keys of Details[aa..-..xx].SerialNo and add error manually. But I don't like this approach and would better like to use validation (server side).

Comment: You cannot apply your `ValidationAttribute` to a collection (you are not generating a form control for the collection). Refer [mvc-collectionvalidation](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-collectionvalidation/blob/master/README.md) for for a project that allows you to apply a `[UniqueInCollection]` attribute

Comment: This will add error to the collection not the particular collection item.

Comment: Which is exactly what should happen. Adding it to each individual item makes no sense - you would be display 2 messages assuming you have one duplicate (one against each item). And then because you do not get client side validation with your attribute, the user must submit the form before seeing the error, and then when they correct it the message does not disappear.